# Get the previous month in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, nifi-processor

I am using the update attribute to check my file if its for previous month.

My file name looks like this `2_EXAMPLE_MMM_2023`.

I am using the expression

```js
${now():minusMonths(1):format('dd_EXAMPLE_MMM_YYYY')}
```

But my version says there is a unexpected token.
I would like to use the **UpdateAttribute** processor to set for just the previous month. Can I get the correct expression to use it?

TIA

Comment: and what is your version?

Comment: and where did you find `minusMonths` function ?

Comment: I am using 1.8 version. Hmm, was trying to use chatGPT, but turns out there is no function as such. That was my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
${now():format("yyyy-MM-01"):toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):minus(1000):format("yyyy-MM-01")}
//^now  ^1st day of month    ^to date             ^minus 1sec ^1st of prev month
```

Comment: 2023-02-01, I got this. Now I should try to get it as Feb, as the file name contains the month name.

Comment: `${now():format("yyyy-MM-01"):toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):minus(1000):format("yyyy-MM-01"):toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):format("MMM")}`

I added the last part to extract the month in words. Thanks a lot Sir. I was banging my head. This is my first work in Nifi, its pretty cool though.

Comment: to get `Feb` just use `MMM` as a format. more about different formats read here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html - because nifi based on java